# proper use of error handling

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

I'm quite new to angularjs and I'm trying to figure out how to use a good and proper error handling when calling web api.

I have two methods which depends on each other, so I need to wait for the first method to finish before calling the second method. But if the web api returns internal server error (of something else), how should I take care of if in a proper way?

My firstMethod causes an error right now, but the $scope.scopeMethod is still keep on going. Should I use the error handling there instead?

```
angular.module("Module")
.controller("MyController",
    function ($scope, $log, SecurityService) {

        $scope.scopeMethod= function() {
            SecurityService.firstMethod()
                .then(function(firstResult) {
                    $scope.firstResult= firstResult;
                    SecurityService.secondMethod(firstResult)
                        .then(function (secondResult) {
                            $scope.secondResult= secondResult;
                            //Do stuff with secondresult

                            });
                        });
                });
        }
    }
)
```

SecurityService:

```
angular.module('Security', []);

angular.module("Security")
.factory("SecurityService",
    function($http, $cookies, $rootScope, $log) {
        var service = {};

        //firstMethod 
        service.firstMethod = function () {

            return $http.get('/api/security/') 
                .then(function(result) {
                    return (result.data);
                }, function(error) {
                    $log.error(error);
                });
        }

        //secondMethod
        service.secondMethod = function(username) {

            return $http.get('/api/security/' + username)
                .then(function(result) {
                    return (result.data);
                });
        }

        return service;
    }
);
```

Comment: Inside the `then` function you can pass 2 parameters (functions) first is `success` and second is for `error`. So what you need to do is in success of first method call second function, in error do nothing. Did you tried using it in that way ?

Comment: So I need an error function in both the method call of first method and in the method itself?

Comment: Yes.. it will be something like `.then(sucess function, error function)`

Comment: It's not working when adding a error function to my controller